# Responsive YouTube embed not displaying in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox, youtube

This embed method appears to be working on all browsers except Firefox; I signed up for a free trial at crossbrowsertesting.com to check. I’m *not* doing a direct iFrame embed, and all the questions and answers I’ve found relate to that. I’m using this method: [A Better Method for Embedding YouTube Videos on your Website](https://www.labnol.org/internet/light-youtube-embeds/27941/). This method:

> embeds the thumbnail image of a YouTube video and the actual video player is loaded only when the user manually clicks the thumbnail

The closest issue I could find on Stack Overflow was [YouTube embed not working in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13226272/youtube-embed-not-working-in-firefox). But this does not apply.

Here are screenshots of it displaying properly in Chrome:

[image]

And not displaying in Firefox:

[image]

In the Firefox image you can see the margin showing up in the inspector as I hover that `<div>`.

When I set an explicit `height` value this thumbnail does show up in Firefox, but it negates the responsiveness of the method.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
  function() {
    var div, n,
      v = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube-player");
    for (n = 0; n < v.length; n++) {
      div = document.createElement("div");
      div.setAttribute("data-id", v[n].dataset.id);
      div.innerHTML = labnolThumb(v[n].dataset.id);
      div.onclick = labnolIframe;
      v[n].appendChild(div);
    }
  });

function labnolThumb(id) {
  var thumb = '<img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ID/hqdefault.jpg">',
    play = '<div class="play"></div>';
  return thumb.replace("ID", id) + play;
}

function labnolIframe() {
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  var embed = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID?autoplay=1";
  iframe.setAttribute("src", embed.replace("ID", this.dataset.id));
  iframe.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
  iframe.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "1");
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);
}
```

```css
.youtube-player {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 56.23%;
  /* Use 75% for 4:3 videos */
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  margin: 5px;
}

.youtube-player iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
  background: transparent;
}

.youtube-player img {
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  border: none;
  height: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: .4s all;
  -moz-transition: .4s all;
  transition: .4s all;
}

.youtube-player img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(75%);
}

.youtube-player .play {
  height: 72px;
  width: 72px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -36px;
  margin-top: -36px;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("//i.imgur.com/TxzC70f.png") no-repeat;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="youtube-player" data-id="VIDEO_ID"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by removing redundant flexbox classes from the parent div. Specifically:

```
frow direction-column
```

(these are from the nice flexbox grid framework [FrowCSS](http://frowcss.com/))

I don't fully understand why, but these must have been interfering with the requried styles in FireFox. Glad I figured it out, I had been wrestling with this 2-3 hours before I posted on SO. Hope this helps someone else in future.

Comment: This was my issue too, using display:flex on my parent container for layout broke the same responsive embed CSS you listed above just in Firefox.

Comment: Just ran into this with an embedded Google Map that wasn't showing in FF no matter what I did. Removed 'display: flex;' from a parent two levels up and it's showing fine now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped a div around the **youtube-player** and set that to display block and added a width of 100%. That solved the problem. Adding those to the youtube-player itself didn't work though.